# how can i access certain content (for example checkbox) of certain child or of all children in an expandable listview?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, expandablelistview

i have this problem since two days, and i search for a solution here, but didnt find any thing for it.

the problem is the following:
i am trying to set the checkboxes, which are a part of every child of an expandable listview.
i am trying to set them, when i set another checkbox, which is not a part of the expandable listview.

so how can i access the checkboxes?

i want to access them from the listener of the external checkbox.

```
chckbxAlleTage.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                        boolean isChecked) {
                    int childrenCount = listAdapter.getChildrenCount(0);
                    if (chckbxAlleTage.isChecked()) {
                        for (int index = 0; index<childrenCount; index++ )
                        {
                            CheckBox tempchckBx = (CheckBox) (listAdapter.getChildView(
                                    0, index, true,findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout1) , expListView))
                                    .findViewById(R.id.chckBx);
                            tempchckBx.setChecked(true);
                        }
                        AnzahlTage = 7;

                    }else
                        {
                            AnzahlTage = 0;
                        }   

                    setEtAnzahlTage();
                }
            });
```

the result of the this code in the listener is that only one checkbox is checked. 
i hope someone can figur out, what is the problem here.

thnx

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle this by changing the data that backs the adapter and not by manually changing the views. The views will get redrawn by the adapter as soon as you scroll anyway.

What you should really be doing is changing the backing DATA layer of the adapter so that when the adapter calls getView it can check to see weather or not the box should be checked. Once you change the backing data to adapter you can call notifyDatasetChanged() on the adapter so it can redraw it's views according to the new data.

If you post your adapter code I can be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your answer.
here is the code of the adapter

```
 private class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private Context _context;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader;       
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context,
            List<String> listDataHeader,
            HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(
                this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

        CheckBox chckBx = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chckBx);
        chckBx.setEnabled(false);
        if (allTageFlag) {
            chckBx.setChecked(true);
        }

        TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv);
        tv.setText(childText);      

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(
                this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

here  is a screenshot of the case  [just paste.it](http://justpaste.it/gr6n)! . ( i cant attach it here :) )
i want to set the checkboxes in the expandable listview when i check the checkbox"Alla Tage"

Answer (score 0):

i solve it in the following way:

```
if (chckbxAlleTage.isChecked()) {

                        for (int index = 0; index < childrenCount; index++ )
                        {
                            if (listAdapter.isChildSelectable(0,index))
                            {   
                                CheckBox tempchckBx =  (CheckBox) (listAdapter.getChildView(
                                        0, index, false, expListView.getChildAt(index+1), expListView))
                                        .findViewById(R.id.chckBx);
                                tempchckBx.setChecked(true);
                            }
                        }       
                    }
```

the use "getChildAt" allows me to acces every child of the listview, and then chose the checkbox of every child and then set them as cheked.